# Copy a config file to the dist directory in webpack

Tags: webpack

I want to copy a file from outside webpack's `entry` or `output` directories. I have a requirement to have a properties file which is completely separated from the bundle.

So I have this structure:

```
/project
   /config
     properties.js
   /dist
     bundle.js
     webpack-created-index.html
   /src
     index.html-with-custom-script-tag
     ...source files and folder here
```

I want to have my webpack.config copy that source-controlled config folder (without fiddling with its content) so my dist folder looks like this:

```
/dist
  /config
    properties.js
  bundle.js
  webpack-created-index.html
```

I want to be able to have my webpack-created index.html load that properties.js file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../config/properties.js"></script>
```

My browser shows a 404, even if I change the relative path in the `<script>` tag to reach back out of `dist` and traverse the file system until it gets to the `config` folder  in `src`.

My webpack.config.js entry / output is as follows:

```
   config.entry = {
     app: './src/app.js'
   };

   config.output = {
     path: __dirname + '/dist',
     publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
     filename: '[name].bundle.js'
   };
```

Is it possible to do this with webpack, or will I need to bring in something like gulp or a node script to do this? My **strong preference** would be to accomplish this with webpack without having to complicate the build with an external script or library.

Comment: U found a solution with webpack config itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use node module cpy-cli.

```
npm install cpy-cli
```

Copy all .html files inside src folder into dist and preserve path structure

```
cpy '**/*.html' '../dist/' --cwd=src --parents
```

I have a simple script which take care it for me

```
"copy-files": "cpy \"**/index.html\" favicon.ico \"../dist\" --cwd=src --parents"
```

To inject file automatically use `html-webpack-plugin`

```
npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

[Read more about it](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin)

Comment: Two questions: How do I wire that script into my normal webpack bundle process? I know I can manually copy it in... I'm looking for a way for webpack to do it. Also, I don't see anything in the html-webpack-plugin to indicate how I can tell it specifically which files to add to the index.html.

Comment: 1. I use it package.json it's very easy there but if you want to use it in webpack then you don't need it you can write some server-side js to make it 2. If you read the docs there is something mentioned about inject.

Comment: I was able to use your "copy-files" idea to successfully copy the file over "physically", but webpack doesn't seem to be aware of it when running the dev-server. I believe the challenge is that if I just use a script to copy the file over to the "dist" folder, webpack has no concept of that file's existence when I run webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Actually webpack dev server listen for file changes or if you add files so it's aware of that. It's not aware of that you are copying files to dist with any npm module but it's listning for changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) very useful in this situation where I need to copy files from src to dist destinations.